# PHP is not closing

Tags: php, html, css

I put in the  tag and inside it is this:

```
$one = "\Images\";
```

I correctly closed the tag itself, but everything after it is being considered part of the tag.

Full code:

```
<div id="skyscraper-ad">
<?php
    $one = "\Images\";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What "tag"? `\Images\`` is **not** a tag.

Comment: Show us the exact output that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape the backslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double):

```
<div id="skyscraper-ad">
<?php
    $one = "\\Images\\";
?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. If the two "//"s are added, wouldn't it mess up the directory?

Comment: A backslash is used to escape several special characters including itself.

Comment: No need to cancel first backslash. `$one = "\Images\\"` this will work fine;

Comment: Thank you. I would thumbs up, but I don't have enough "reputation".

Answer (score 1):

In PHP the `\` character is used to escape an immediately following character that could be interpreted as 'not part of the string'.

eg. If you were to run this:

```
echo '\'hello';
```

it would output: `'hello`.

In your code, you're escaping the ending `'` which will make PHP throw an error.

`echo '\Images\\';` on the other hand will output `\Images\`